# Using something like RackTest Driver for non-testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, capybara, net-http

I have a few websites that I need to login to daily to grab statistics and put them into the database for another application and I'd like to automate this.

I'd like to use something like what Capybara uses with the RackTest Driver, but I can't seem to get RackTest to work outside of a test environment.

The things that I need it to do is:

1) maintain a session on the websites

2) be headless

3) Use ruby

4) if possible I don't want to use Jruby (so that eliminates Celerity)

Does anyone know if there is some tool that can help me do this? Or possibly a way to make Net::HTTP to maintain a session between requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like Mechanize does exactly what I need.

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html